# Digital clock in android 4.1?

Tags: android

I was not able to drag and drop digital clock in android 4.1, but surprisingly able to drag & drop Analog clock !

The error message :

> The following classes could not be found:
>   - DigitalClock (Change to android.widget.DigitalClock, Fix Build Path, Edit XML)

[image]

Comment: Your question is too vague. Explain, please.

Comment: I have a very small app and wanna put a digital clock there in my main.xml file but getting the above written error. On the other hand if i drag & drop analog clock it works fine. Hope i'm clear..will upload the screenshot shortly..

Comment: guys pls hav a look :     http://i1117.photobucket.com/albums/k596/hitmanx07/digital.jpg

Comment: Wondering wat's soo complex in this question so that i have to elaborate.I mean everything is crystal clear( just trying to create digital clock widget on my xml file with simple drag and drop.)?????

Comment: Actually im looking the same but ignore this and Run and will be fine.

Comment: Digital Clock is depreciated above api level 17 its recommended that you uses TextClock and here is its support library which work for me https://github.com/vojtech/android-textclock-backport/branches

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I received the same error in the Eclipse IDE when I dragged and dropped the Digital Clock, but upon running it there were no issues and the clock appeared correctly.  It appears that the error is just spurious and can be ignored.

The other thing to note is that [Digital Clock has been deprecated as of API level 17](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/DigitalClock.html) and if you're able to target API level 17 or later, [Text Clock](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextClock.html) is the widget to use.  When dragging one in, I received no errors.

Answer (score 0):

I hope you aren't missing either of these line in your XML code.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <!-- at the very beginning of your XML code -->


<root xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" ... > <!-- inside the first element (e.g. rootor anything else) in your XML layout code -->
```

Comment: NO, Man everything is fine like  i said issue comes when i try to use digital clock..

Comment: Might sound weird but sometimes Eclipse causes trouble due t no reasons. Maybe it is facing some problems with android.widget. Have tried cleaning the project? Or even make a new project if that doesn't work ? Restarted eclipse ?

Comment: btw, code is working fine but wanna figure out why i'm getting this error message from graphic layout editor and if it is not able to find the android.widget there in xml then why and how it gets complied and run.

Comment: Oh, I did not realise that your code was working. Well, in that case I guess it's nothing but some problem with eclipse. Keeps happening. (to me at least)